# Multi body animation in python returns static picture

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here is a program that I have written to do an animation in `matplotlib`. The program concerns a system of 18 particles arranged initially in a hexagonal lattice. The initial configuration is given under the definition of `simPoints(simData)`.

The system is evolved over time according to the rule `x[i]=x[i]+L/2.0`, in both x and y direction. Particles going out of the window are brought in through the other side. These updates are mentioned under the function `simData()`.

But all I get out of this code is a static picture of the initial configuration of particles.

```
from numpy import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

L=1         # lattice constant = sigma*2**0.5 (Let)

x=zeros(18,float)
y=zeros(18,float)


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ANIMATION ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
def simData():
    t = 1
    while t<=20:
        for i in range(18):
            x[i]=x[i]+L/2.0
            y[i]=y[i]+L/2.0
            if x[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
                x[i]=x[i]-L*3
            elif x[i]<0:
                x[i]=L*3-x[i]
            if y[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
                y[i]=y[i]-L*3
            elif y[i]<0:
                y[i]=L*3-y[i]
        t=t+1
    yield x, y

def simPoints(simData):
    k=0
    for i in range(0,6,1):
        for j in range(0,6,1):
            if (i+j)%2==0:
                x[k]=i*L*.5+.25*L
                y[k]=j*L*.5+.25*L
                k=k+1
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line, = ax.plot(x, y,'bo', ms=8)
ax.set_ylim(0, L*3)
ax.set_xlim(0, L*3)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

How can I animate the lattice? I have a feeling that the argument `interval=100` is not used wisely.

Comment: This question is just a continuation of another question that I asked yesterday. I had to ask again because, though my primary confusion had been removed by @Reblochon, I had trouble modifying the program to fit my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some minor changes in Your code, as You can see below. It's animating now, however the `simPoints()` is commented out. The major issue is that if You initialize the points like that, after each step they end up in the same places. Dots move, but another dots take their places, so it looks like the plot isn't moving. You may want to change the `simData()` function, for example make the changes more subtle or random, to avoid that case.

```
from numpy import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

L=1         # lattice constant = sigma*2**0.5 (Let)

x=array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18])
#x=zeros(18,float)
y=zeros(18,float)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ANIMATION ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
def simData():
    t = 1
    while t<=20:
        for i in range(18):
            x[i]=x[i]+L/2.0
            y[i]=y[i]+L/2.0
            if x[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
                x[i]=x[i]-L*3
            elif x[i]<0:
                x[i]=L*3-x[i]
            if y[i]>L*3:                    # translate back the particle if it goes out of window limit 0 to L*cell
                y[i]=y[i]-L*3
            elif y[i]<0:
                y[i]=L*3-y[i]
        t=t+1

def simPoints():
    k=0
    for i in range(0,6,1):
        for j in range(0,6,1):
            if (i+j)%2==0:
                x[k]=i*L*.5+.25*L
                y[k]=j*L*.5+.25*L
                k=k+1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
#simPoints()
line, = ax.plot(x, y,'bo', ms=8)
ax.set_ylim(0, L*3)
ax.set_xlim(0, L*3)

def animate(i):
    simData()
    print x
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=False, interval=100, frames=200)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation is all right and works. Your Problem is the symmetry in your logic. To test the animation just add some random value:

```
def simPoints(simData):
    k=0
    for i in range(0,6,1):
        for j in range(0,6,1):
            if (i+j)%2==0:
                # just add some randomness to see the random x-movement
                x[k]=i*L*.5+.25*L + random.random(1)
                y[k]=j*L*.5+.25*L
                k=k+1
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
```

Every point xy you calculate is occupied beforehand by an other. Thus it seems static. If you want to see the in-between steps you need to update your data generation (esp. get rid of the modulus). Or expand the boundaries/graph-limits, so you can see the dots move.